# jQuery validate plugin allows submit when validation fails. Form is using .load

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have built a form which is paginated (jQuery ajax style) over 6 pages.  I'm trying to get the jQuery validate plugin to work with it.

At the bottom of the form is a 'next' button which submits the values for that page to the database and loads the next 'page' into the #pagination div using jQuery .load().

I have just added jQuery validation to the form using the [jQuery validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), but the validation flashes on the screen for a second and the page moves on to the next page anyway.  I'd be grateful for any help!  I'd like to allow the form to move to the next page if the validation is successful, but not if it is unsuccessful.  Here is my code (I have boiled it down to be as simple as possible):

#### jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#survey").validate();   
    var page=1; //Set first page on load
    jQuery("#pagination").load("survey_"+page+".htm");

    jQuery("#next").click(function(){

        if(page !== 6){
            page=page+1;}
        if(page == 6){
            jQuery('#next').replaceWith('<button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>');
        }
        else
        {page == 6;}

    jQuery("#pagination").load("survey_"+page+".htm");
 });
```

#### HTML

```
<form class="survey" id="survey" method="post" action="">
    <div id="pagination">
</div>
<div class="nav"><input id="prev" type="submit" value="Previous" ><input class="submit" id="next" value="Next" name="submit" type="submit" /></div>
</form>
```

The form pages are in 6 separate files called survey_1.htm, survey_2.html....survey_6.htm, and as you can see above, they are loaded using .load().

As mentioned, I'd like to allow the form to move to the next page if the validation is successful, but not if it is unsuccessful. At the moment, the validation flashes on screen before the next page is loaded.

Many thanks!

Comment: Show the rest of the code please.  If this is about jQuery Validate plugin, where is your jQuery containing `.validate()`?

Comment: Apologies!  Good spot - have now included the validate bit, which is rather crucial!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Quote OP:**  "As mentioned, I'd like to allow the form to move to the next page if the validation is successful, but not if it is
>   unsuccessful. At the moment, the validation flashes on screen before
>   the next page is loaded."

It's moving to the next page because your page loading logic is bypassing the built-in click handler of the Validation plugin.

It's not very clear to me how your page loading scheme is ultimately going to work.  However, in order to use `ajax` along with the jQuery Validate plugin, you would leverage its [built-in `submitHandler` callback function](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).  In other words, the `submitHandler` function is only fired off when the form passes the validation test.

Something like this...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#survey").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // your ajax loading logic
            // form.submit(); // use this to finally submit form data at the last step
            return false;  // prevent form submit because you are doing the ajax
        }
    });

});
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/zpkm2/**

---

Also note your code:

```
else
    {page == 6;}
```

should probably be:

```
else
    {page = 6;}
```

[`==` is for *comparison* of value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators), and `=` is for *setting* the value.

Comment: You are brilliant!  Thanks so much - it works an absolute treat :)  I'll paste the code below for the benefit of others :D  Thanks again - really appreciate your speedy response.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you're looking to validate the form that came from the method .load(), try this here:

**HTML**

```
<div class="continent-type">
     <label for="people">What is your continent?</label>
     <input type="radio" name="continent" value="A">The Americas
     <input type="radio" name="continent" value="E">European
</div>
<div id="form-load"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
function validateForm(form){
     form.validate({
          rules:{
               // rules...
          },
          messages:{
               // messages...
     });
};
jQuery('input[name=continent]').on('click', function(){

     var continent= jQuery(this).val();

     jQuery("#form-load").load('/get-form.html', {continent:continent}, function(){
          validateForm($(this).find('form'));
     });
});
```